# WebDriver - Captured screenshots seem to have a red or orange hue

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

This might seem trivial, but I'm not able to get around this.

I'm capturing a snapshot of a page using WebDriver, and somehow the screenshot has this orange (or red) hue all over it.

[image: Snapshot taken by WebDriver]

This is my code:

```
private static BufferedImage getScreenshot() throws IOException {
        byte[] bytes = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
        return ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    }
```

I've tried the various options for `OutputType` (`OutputType.BYTES`, `OutputType.FILE`, `OutputType.BASE64`), and all give me the same result.

My environment is as follows:

1. Windows 10
2. Screen Resolution: 1920 x 1080
3. WebDriver version 3.13.0
4. Browser - Tried with both Firefox (Quantum 61.0.1 using GeckoDriver v0.21.0 x64)
5. Also tried with Chrome (version 67.0.3396.99) with Chrome driver version 2.41 win32.

Got same result even with selenium 2.53.1

What am I missing? Or could this be a bug in the driver(s)? I guess that would be highly unlikely as I'm not able to find anyone on the internet with the same problem.

Thanks,
Sriram

Comment: I am here because I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I changed from "jpg" to "png" and it's not taking red screenshots anymore.